# Above and Below Display Arrangement in El Capitan

Tags: macos, display

Now with more El Capitan, and a change of screen layout.  *Apple seems to be deliberately mocking me!*

I have a laptop running <del>Yosemite</del> El Capitan with an external monitor sitting <del>above</del> next to the laptops display.  When I am logged in I have the display arrangement mimicking the physical <del>above and below</del> side by side layout.  This works and is good.

However when I am logged out the <del>Yosemite</del> El Capitan login screen reverts to an <del>side by side</del> above and below arrangement.

I would like <del>Yosemite</del> El Capitan to keep the side by side arrangement even when I am logged out, but the display arrangement in the System Preferences is per logged in account.

So what would I do to set the arrangement when there is no logged in account?

Comment: Wow - I haven't tested this, but that sure seems aggravating if it's simply a bug in the software.

Comment: Don't think this is a bug, in my case that configuration works fine.

Comment: @jherran So your monitors remain in the same arrangement when logged out? Now I wonder if it is hardware related or perhaps having multiple accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have just solved it.  I have two accounts on this Mac, my Admin account and my daily use account.  The admin account didn't have the same screen orientation as the the daily use account, and on the login screen the admin account was listed first.  I suspect that when no accounts are logged in that OS X grabs the screen configuration of the first account that it finds - which happened to be the admin account in my case.